# C: Problem in comparing two strings in a function

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, strstr

Good morning everyone, I have to simulate the operation of the `strstr()` function with a function written by me.

In the code I slide the original string in a temporary string and then the comparison with the string to look for, if they are equal it should return `1`.

But even if the strings are equal and of the same length the code never enters the `if` cycle and therefore never returns `1`.

My code:

```
int *strstr_new(char *s7, char *s8) {

int length_s7 = strlen(s7);
int length_s8 = strlen(s8);
char search_string[length_s8];
printf("%d\n", length_s8);

for(int i=0; i<length_s7; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<length_s8; j++) {
        search_string[j] = s7[i+j];
        search_string[j+1] = '\0';
    }
    printf("%s\n", s8);
    printf("%s\n", search_string);
    printf("%d\n", length_s8);
    printf("%d\n", strlen(search_string));
    //search_string[length_s8+1] = '\0';
    if(search_string == s8) {
        return(1);
    }
}
if(search_string != s8) {
    return(NULL);
}}
```

Does someone have an idea of where I'm wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Start by looking at your [compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756). Then ask yourself this question: if ny function returns a *pointer*, what should it *point at*?

Comment: Next, write this on the classroom chalkboard 100 times: *A string is a null terminated character array. I shall always provide an extra character for the null terminator.*

Comment: Next, fire up the debugger. Or use a little paper-and-pencil debugger. You have `s7[i+j]` What's the maximum value of `i+j` again?

Comment: Next, read about [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp). Why do you think this function is needed? Where could you have used it in your code?

Comment: When you have fixed all of the above problems, test your function with inputs of 2 million characters each.

Comment: @Cb95 The function does not maje a sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function declaration

```
int *strstr_new(char *s7, char *s8);
```

looks very strange.

For example why is the return type `int *`?
Why are function parameters named `s7` and `s8` instead of for example `s1` and `s2`?
Why are not the function parameters qualified with `const`?

Creating a variable length array within the function is inefficient and redundant and can lead to stack exhaustion.

```
char search_string[length_s8];
```

This loops

```
for(int j=0; j<length_s8; j++) {
    search_string[j] = s7[i+j];
    search_string[j+1] = '\0';
}
```

invokes undefined behavior because this statement

```
search_string[j+1] = '\0';
```

writes beyond the array when `j` is equal to `length_s8 - 1`.

In this statement

```
if(search_string == s8) {
```

there are compared two pointers and it is evident that they are unequal because they point to different arrays.

Without using standard C functions except the function `strlen` (that could be also defined explicitly) the function can be declared and defined the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * strstr_new( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = NULL;
    
    size_t n1 = strlen( s1 );
    size_t n2 = strlen( s2 );
    
    if ( !( n1 < n2 ) )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0, n = n1 - n2 + 1; p == NULL && i < n; i++ )
        {
            size_t j = 0;
        
            while ( j < n2 && s1[i + j] == s2[j] ) ++j;
        
            if ( j == n2 ) p = ( char * )( s1 + i );
        }
    }
    
    return p;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const char *s1 = "strstr_new";
    const char *s2 = "str";
    
    for ( const char *p = s1; ( p  = strstr_new( p, s2 ) ) != NULL; ++p )
    {
        puts( p );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
strstr_new
str_new
```

If you are allowed to use standard string functions along with `strlen` then the loop within the function `strstr_new` can be simplified the following way

```
for ( size_t i = 0, n = n1 - n2 + 1; p == NULL && i < n; i++ )
{
    if ( memcmp( s1 + i, s2, n2 ) == 0 ) p = ( char * )( s1 + i );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem in your code is comparing strings with == operator. Both `search_string` and `s8` are `char` pointers, which means you're comparing addresses of different variables, obviously to return False. Try adding another for loop to compare each `char` in `search_string` to the corresponding `char` in `s8` (using the dereferencing operator *).

Comment: yes now i create a function that works like strcmp()!

Answer (score 1):

- Your string comparisons won't work because you are comparing the addresses of those strings instead of the strings themselves, you'd what to use something like `strcmp` or `memcmp` to compare two strings.
- Your return type is also not compatible with the return you have particularly if the strings match. I'd return 1 if the string is found and 0 if it's not, for that you'd need to change the return type to `int` only.
- The second string comparison is unneeded, you already test the existance of the substring inside the loop so you just need to return 0 if the loop finds it's way to the end.
- Lastly the temporary string is too short and will allow for access outside its bounds, inside the loop.

  *e.g.* if `length_s8` is `4` will write to
  `search_string[4]`, `5th` index, out the bounds of the array.

```
int strstr_new(char *s7, char *s8) //return 1 for found, 0 for not found
{
    int length_s7 = strlen(s7);
    int length_s8 = strlen(s8);   
    char search_string[length_s8 + 1];//you'd want to avoid buffer overflow

    for (int i = 0; i < length_s7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < length_s8; j++)
        {
            search_string[j] = s7[i + j];
            search_string[j + 1] = '\0';
        }

        if (!strcmp(search_string, s8))
        {
            return 1; //if the string is found return 1 immediately
        }
    }
    return 0; //if it reaches this point, no match was found
}
```

A couple of tests:

```
printf("%d\n", strstr_new("this is my string", "this i"));
printf("%d\n", strstr_new("this is my string", "ringo"));
printf("%d\n", strstr_new("this is my string", "ring"));
printf("%d\n", strstr_new("this is my strin", "ths"));
```

Output:

```
1
0
1
0
```